# Python Client on Windows Communication Foundation

Tags: python, c#, wcf, service, client

Recently I started playing with Windows Communication Foundation on Visual Studio creating simple services and clients to call them. Now I wanted to create a client in Python Using zeep library (you can find here the resources https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) and call a simple service created in C# on Visual Studio which gets in input two integers and returns their sum.

Here is the Visual studio code in the App.config file with all the addressing necessary to call the service (which is hosted in an application on my pc):

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.CalculatorService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/WcfServiceLibrary1/CalculatorService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Se non è completamente qualificato, l'indirizzo è relativo all'indirizzo di base fornito sopra -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.ICalculator">
      <!-- 
          Durante la distribuzione è necessario rimuovere o sostituire l'elemento Identity seguente in modo 
          che rispecchi l'identità con cui viene eseguito il servizio distribuito. Se viene rimosso, WCF dedurrà 
           automaticamente un'identità appropriata.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- L'endpoint di scambio metadati viene utilizzato dal servizio per offrire una migliore visualizzazione ai client. --> 
    <!-- L'endpoint non utilizza un'associazione protetta e deve essere protetto o rimosso prima della distribuzione -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Now I just created a small python code with library zeep to call the service:

```
import zeep
from zeep import Client

print("Connectin to service...")
wsdl = 'http://localhost:8000/WcfServiceLibrary1/CalculatorService/'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl)
print("Connected to service!")
result = client.Add(3, 4)
print(client_admin)
```

The Client successfully connects to the srvice but when i run the python code it returns

> Connecting to service...
> Connected to service!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Test_zeep.py", line 8, in 
> result = client.Add(3, 4)
>
> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'Add'

Do you have any ideas? Why does my client not "recognise" the method `Add(n1, n2)` which is present in my service?

If I create a C# client with Visual Studio and call the service, it works perfectly, so maybe it is a problem of the service?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you try to use basichttpbinding first to see if it can be called successfully. I suspect that this problem may be caused by zeep not supporting wsDualHttpBinding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already tried changing the binding type using Dual, WS and Basic but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try to use suds: https://pypi.org/project/suds/

Comment: The problem is that suds looks obsolete and doesn't work with Python 3....